# Using WPF trying to create directories and subdirectories in user downloads but getting an access denied error

Tags: c#, wpf, permissions

[image: error message ss]

```
 private void CreateDirectories( )
 {
     //define path for backupFolderDirectory
     string backupFolderDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads");
     try
     {
         // Check if BrowserBackup exists, if it does, delete it
         if (Directory.Exists(backupFolderDirectory))
         {
             Directory.Delete(backupFolderDirectory, true);
             MessageBox.Show($"Deleted existing backup folder.");
         }
         else
         {
             // Create browserbackup Directory in downloads
             Directory.CreateDirectory(backupFolderDirectory);
             MessageBox.Show($"Created backup folder.");

             // Define path for chrome directory
             string chromeDirectory = Path.Combine(backupFolderDirectory, "Chrome");
             // Create Chrome directory
             Directory.CreateDirectory(chromeDirectory);

             // Define path for Edge Directory
             string edgeDirectory = Path.Combine(backupFolderDirectory, "Edge");
             // Create Edge directory
             Directory.CreateDirectory(edgeDirectory);

             // Define path for firefox directory
             string firefoxDirectory = Path.Combine(backupFolderDirectory, "firefoxDirectory");
             // Create firefox Directory
             Directory.CreateDirectory(firefoxDirectory);

             MessageBox.Show($"Created Browser Directories.");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show($"Error creating directories: {ex.Message}");
     }
 }



 private void BackupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

     CreateDirectories();
 }
```

When on my work workstation did not have this issue. The account I am trying to use right now is an admin.

Comment: Which method is throwing that exception?

Comment: That exception is thrown when i press the backup button. The backup button calls the createdirectories() method

Comment: I mean where in that method does it throw? Do you know how to use a debugger? It will tell you exactly where your problem occurs.

Comment: This exception is thrown when it tries to delete the directory if it exists (which in this case it does not exist)

Comment: If your solution is worth sharing, please do so.

Comment: You shouldn't create a backup in the download folder. This should go to the AppData folder. However, you must ensure that the file is not read-only (check the file's/directory's attributes and that it is not locked because it is used by another process (including Windows processes).

Comment: The solution was             
string backupFolderDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads", "BrowserBackup");


It was trying to delete the downloads folder instead of only deleting the browser backupfolder in the downloads (if it exists)

Comment: Look at that, you had deleted folder of the user! Good example why you should avoid doing such stunts in public user folders.  As mentioned in my comment before, you should create such a directory in the application folder of your application.  There is no use in creating a backup directory in the Downloads folder which gets periodically cleaned by the user or the environment. That's not the purpose of a backup. Store it at a save location, like the AppData folder of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In case your application was not run as Administrator you can restart your application and ask for Admin's privileges.

```
 public void AskForAdminPrivileges()
 {
   try
     {

     var appName= System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
     //Define process which should start:
     ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     processInfo.FileName = appName;
     processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
     processInfo.Verb = "runas";         

     Process.Start(processInfo );

     }
     catch (Exception exp)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
     }
 }
```